# SRAM Hydraulic brake stuck (with a changed bite point) after landing/impact

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, sram

I experienced a weird problem on my SRAM level t 2 piston brakes.

I like hopping my bike around, e.g. bunny hopping onto curbs. Sometimes, if the impact is hard, the brake lever would have reduced travel. It feels like the pistons would engage the rotor at half of the normal travel (as if the brake is stuck in the middle). At that moment, if I grab the brake hard, I hear a clicking noise (from around the lever), after which it would function normally with the normal travel -- until I hit something hard again.

Never tried bleeding, but as the brake feels solid when engaged, I assume that bubble in the hydraulic line is not likely to be the cause. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks! The problem is driving me crazy, and it is dangerous to descend with these brakes with changing bite points.

---

Edit: I found the problem. If I bend the brake lever towards the opposite direction (e.g. away from the handlebar), the lever would be stuck at a different position, which can be corrected by a pull to the handlebar.

When I hop, my hand position would change slightly which bends the brake lever towards the wrong direction, which is the cause of the problem (instead of the vibration).

It is still kind of annoying as it is distracting when riding. But as least the problem is located.

Comment: Changing bite point on Shimanos is because of excessively viscous oil, but this sounds like a mechanical issue with the levers.

Comment: Indeed, this feels like a mechanical issue. Another detail is the clicking noise comes from the level.

Comment: I know you said there's a noise in the lever, but symptoms sure sound like the issue is at the wheel. Perhaps the wheel is moving in the dropout and thereby moving the rotor? I would double check that the wheel is very secure in the dropouts. ALternatively, the caliper is moving, but that seems less likely, though a caliper movement would be more consistent with it correcting itself when braking.